# C++ reading the first line from a file using .getline()

Tags: c++

Im having a hard time understanding how to read the first line of a file. im trying to read the 1st line of a file and then check to see if its blank. this is what i came up with but still not working

```
void buildTree( NodePtr &root, ifstream& input )
    {
        char line [50];
        line= input.getline();

        if ( line ==  NULL )
        {
           root = NULL;
           return;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a `std::string`?

Comment: because i haven't been thought that yet so im supposed to arrays instead.

Comment: @GWW and plus, we are programing in C. my prof said something about how C does not have a standard string library.

Comment: @user1896464 That’s not C code.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, its weird. the book we use is a C book. he teaches in C++ and all our projects are in C++. when we got to strings, he said something about how C does not have a standard string library. so we are to use arrays in all our assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void buildTree( NodePtr &root, ifstream& input )
    {
        char line [50];
        input.getline(line, sizeof line);

        if (strlen(line) == 0)
        {
           root = NULL;
           return;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong the format for getline() is as follows.
If you are using char array :

```
char buffer[256];
input.getline(buffer, 256);
```

If you are using string :

```
string buffer;
getline(input, buffer);
```